# How can I immediately flush the php output buffer to the browser in Drupal hook_menu, flush & ob_flush not working?

Tags: routes

I'm trying to immediately send the php output buffer to the browser while in a Drupal hook_menu but it doesn't seem to be working.  I use the following code on a non-Drupal php page on the same Apache site and it works perfectly (prints each line to the browser when flush is called), I put it in a hook_menu function and it waits until the end of the routine and then shows everything at once.

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';
```

Comment: Drupal uses the various buffer flush routines to allow all of its various *.tpl.php templates (and included php) to actually work, so, I'm afraid this is "just the way it is."

Comment: Not sure I follow you.  So you're saying that there is zero way to immediately flush the php output buffer to the browser in Drupal?

Comment: Pretty much yes.  As Drupal builds the page, it pulls in all sorts of templates, and to do that it runs/executes them, so it needs buffering to get/trap their output. It then puts that all together at the end in the correct order.  To use buffering inside hook_menu() just won't work.  For more info, just grep ob_ in the include/* files to see what I mean. If you are wanting to do a countdown or something that requires timed output, I'd investigate using javascript/jquery.

Comment: Actually it was for debugging a long-running php process. Thanks for the info.